# Strange dimension change of a nested array after readline and sympify operation?

Tags: julia

If I understand correctly, in Julia m = [[1,2],[3,4]] is a two-dimensional vector with each vector of two elements. And this fact won't change after the operation of sympify

```
ms = sympy.sympify(m)
size(ms)
```

The output will still be (2,), as expected.

However, if I create a file test.txt with just one line [[1,2],[3,4]] and run

```
using SymPy
open("test.txt") do io
    while ! eof(io)
        m = readline(io)
        println(m)
        ms = sympy.sympify(m)
        println(ms)
    end
end
```

The output will be

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
Sym[1 2; 3 4]
```

Namely, now **ms suddenly changes to a two-by-two matrix**! I really cannot understand this (since the dimension of m after readline stays to be (2,) as before). Could someone explain this for me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sympy, but in the first case you are passing a Julia object to `sympify`, while in the loop you're giving it a string. Perhaps the string is parsed the way python does it, since `[[1,2], [3,4]]` is a 2d array in python, but is a one-dimensional vector in Julia.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I tried `sympy.sympify("[[1,2],[3,4]]")`, it gives a two-by-two matrix instead of a vector. Thank you!

Comment: I have to say such mixed characteristics are kind of annoying...

Comment: I guess there's no going around that, since `[[1,2],[3,4]]` is different in Python and Julia. The solution would be to stick to one language and, FWIW, there is the recently released https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl for symbolic manipulations in Julia.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can define your own parsing function to read lines from a file into the vector of vectors:

```
function myparse(T::Type, s::String)
    [[parse(T, c) for c in element if isnumeric(c)] for element in split(s, "],[")]
end
```

Then, you can simply do:

```
using SymPy

m = open("test.txt") do io
    myparse(Int, readline(io))
end
println(typeof(m)) # Vector{Vector{Int64}} (alias for Array{Array{Int64, 1}, 1})
```

Then,

```
julia> ms = sympy.sympify(m)
2-element Vector{Sym}:
 [1  2]
 [3  4]
```